# Is it possible to change the font size of errors in PHP xdebug?

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm using the xdebug extension for php on my mac.
It's great but the font size of errors is just to small !

[this is what my screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRiyV.jpg)

I've looked around in php.ini, found how to change the color of errors, but not the font size.

Couldn't find any info on that.
Any idea ?

Thanks in advance to anyone !

Comment: You can use the browser zoom.